# Given a function and compute the definite integral of its inverse

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, inverse, inverse-function

So I have a function
$$ f(x)=x^{3}-12x^{2}+69x+6 $$

The question askes me to find the relationship between $$\int_{1}^{2} f(x)dx$$ $$and$$ $$\int_{64}^{104} f^{-1}(x)dx$$

And compute the value of $\int_{64}^{104} f^{-1}(x)dx$

I found out that $f(1) = 64$ and $f(2) = 104 $

But not sure how do I proceed.

I could not find how this is related to the course material presented this week, and am completely lost to be honest. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

By [Laisant's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions), if $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, then
$$
\int_{c}^df^{-1}(x)dx+\int_a^bf(x)dx=bd-ac
$$

---

Notes.

When $f$ is differentiable, one can prove the result by change of variables:
$$
\int_c^d f^{-1}(y)dy=\int_a^b f^{-1}(f(x))f'(x)dx=\int_a^b xf'(x)dx=xf(x)|_{a}^b-\int_a^bf(x)dx
$$

---

A proof without words:

[image]

Comment: Hi, quick follow up question: How did $\int_{c}^{d} f^{-1}(y)dy$  become $\int_{a}^{b} f^{-1} (f(x))f'(x)dx$ ? I understand $y=f(x)$, but how did the rest happen?

Comment: @SirouEwei if you set $y=f(x)$ then $dy=f'(x)dx$ so $f^{-1}(y)dy=f^{-1}(f(x))f'(x)dx$.

Comment: what about the intervals? How did change from $\int_{c}^{d} f^{-1}(y)dy$ to $\int_{a}^{b} f^{-1}(y)dy$

Comment: Originally $y$ ranges from $c$ to $c$. After change of variable $y=f(x)$, $x$ ranges from $a$ to $b$. You can tells this from the picture.// Have you ever learned change of variables before?